having generic fields based on model objects in forms.py in django
We have a model called Permission and we have listed it in a form in django template like this:
                            {% for item in permissions %}
                            <tr>
                              <td class="text-nowrap">{{ item.app }}</td>
                              <td>
                                <div class="d-flex">
                                  <div class="form-check me-3 me-lg-5 mb-0 mt-0">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="{{ item.app }}_add" id="{{ item.app }}ManagementWrite">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="{{ item.app }}ManagementWrite">add</label>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-check me-3 me-lg-5 mb-0 mt-0">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="{{ item.app }}_read" id="{{ item.app }}ManagementRead">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="{{ item.app }}ManagementRead">read</label>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-check me-3 me-lg-5 mb-0 mt-0">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="{{ item.app }}_update" id="{{ item.app }}ManagementUpdate">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="{{ item.app }}ManagementUpdate">update</label>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-check mb-0 mt-0">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="{{ item.app }}_delete" id="{{ item.app }}ManagementDelete">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="{{ item.app }}ManagementDelete">delete</label>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}

So here We have four options for read , write , update and delete for each object in the Permission table .
But How can i make a form in forms.py for this that i have BoleanFields for each access level?
for example four field for ticket app (read , write , update , delete) and four field for users app as the same .

Can you include the Permission model?

you can use ListView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView in django generic views.
this views give you a option to define a form_class or by default after define a model for them, they are using the model form and you can access the form in template with {{ form }}.
